# Forwarding different subdomains to the same upstream, same ip

Tags: nginx, next.js, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have a simple question for someone who really knows nginx, I'm offering 10 matic crypto as a thank you.

I have a NextJS app running on ubuntu localhost:3020
I have to subdomains, staking & marketplace that I both want pointed to the nextjs app, but on different paths

staking.domain.com -> localhost:3020/staking

marketplace.domain.com -> localhost:3020/marketplace

I managed to get it working a bit, but you still need to use the /marketplace after the domain, like marketplace.domain.com/marketplace. I'd like it without a path, just the subdomain using nginx to reverse proxy to a path.

```
  upstream demoPROD {
    server 127.0.0.1:3020;
}

limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=demo:200m rate=99r/s;


server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name staking.demo.com;
    root /root/projects/demo_prod/public;
    
    limit_req zone=demo burst=90 nodelay;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/demo_staking/certificateBundle.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/demo_staking/private.key;
    

    location / {
        root /root/projects/demo_prod/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @demoPROD;
        limit_req zone=one burst=200 nodelay;
        proxy_pass http://demoPROD;
    }

    location @demoPROD {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://demoPROD;
    }
    

    expires $expires;
}


server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name marketplace.demo.com;
    root /root/projects/demo_prod/public;
    
    limit_req zone=demo burst=90 nodelay;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/demo_marketplace/certificateBundle.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/demo_marketplace/private.key;
    
 location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ @demoPROD;

        proxy_pass            http://demoPROD/store/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

        location @demoPROD {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://demoPROD;
    }

    expires $expires;
}
```